# Why google search console need to verify dns txt?

Tags: google-search-console, netlify, hugo

First I build blog in hugo and deploy with netlify.

Verifying with file or txt, it isn't rendered in my case. I try to put content folder, also themes folder. So i found alternative way using google Web master center. And then, just add html tag. Finally, I got Verification completed. But, I can't use search console, yet. Because I'm not verified.

Why and How can correct?

Comment: did you use netlify to manage your dns?

Answer (score 1):

If you want static content, rendered as-is, place it in Hugo's static directory and it will be added directly to the output public directory without alteration. Alternatively, you could use a meta tag to verify; just place that in your base layout; typically `layouts/_default/baseofhtml.html`